# C++ | List of object

Tags: c++, list

I have list of `Item` (some class) and this class has 3 variables `price`,`name`,and `count`.

I want to know how do I delete all the items which their price is `320`.

Comment: go through the list, check if the price is 320 and delete them?

Comment: How do I do this? Can you show me in code?

Comment: Looks like "do my homework". Please, check this page before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8):

What about this?

```
std::list<Item> l;
//...
l.remove_if ([] (Item const& i) {
    return i.price == 320;
});
```

See the doc:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove

Comment: +1 because it's a thousand times shorter and more readable than my answer. :P

Comment: it's show me "the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function object is: const item"

Comment: I think you may need to add that this is only going to work if the poster is using c++11. His question only has the tag c++.

Comment: While this is a good point about removing from std::list, I suspect while he says "list", he might not consciously refer to std::list. Which shouldn't be the first container choice unless you know _why_ you choose it.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `std::list` as the container, use `std::list::remove_if`; see @wilx answer.

---

If you do *not* use `std::list`, but rather another container, use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

```
#include <algorithm>

list.erase(std::remove_if(list.begin(), list.end(), [] (Item const& i) {
    return i.price == 320;
}), list.end());
```

Comment: You must wrap that in list.erase( std::remove_if( ... ), list.end() )

Comment: @Zoidberg: You should probably also erase the elements from the list. This will just shuffle the order and make some elements have unspecified contents.

Comment: `list.begin()`, not `begin(list)`?

Comment: @Bill: C++11 add a `std::begin` and `std::end`, so `begin(list) is equivalent to `list.begin()`.

Comment: Right, begin(list) would be better when using C++11. Might be worth to  state the need of C++11 explicitly and add a C++03 variant.

Comment: @Bill I and many prefer `.begin()` notation except when the container is of a template parameter type. When the type is known (i.e. not a template parameter), it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Except that this is _not_ the way to do it with `std::list`.  Because `std::list` is so efficient in erasing a single item, given it's iterator, it has a member function `remove_if`, which actually does remove, immediately, without copying anything.

Comment: @JamesKanze Right. I'll leave the answer here for people not using `std::list`.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are using c++ and not c++11 - it is something like:

```
bool my_predicate (const Item& value) { return (value.price==320); }

void foo() {
  std::list<Item> l;
  //...
  l.remove_if (my_predicate);
}
```